# User vs database driven UI updates

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, realm, nscollectionview

Let's say I have a collection view populated with objects from a Realm.

If the user asks the collection view to delete an item, what's the most responsive way to handle that?

Should -

a) the request be sent to the realm and the UI update be driven by a new notification

or

b)  the collection view delete the item immediately (both visually and from its own model) and then silently accept the new model from the Realm notification.

Are Realm updates fast enough for UI updates?

Answer (score 0):

If `Realm` database works like cache and you also have data on server it's prefer to use the first way, because for any reason request for server can failed and in this case you probably don't want to delete the item. And if `Realm` is only one place for your data you can use the second way, because you don't need to handle unnecessary steps (i mean handle `addNotificationBlock` and do some actions with ui), you just need to delete item in ui and delete item in realm, that's it.

> Are Realm updates fast enough for UI updates?

Of course, in this case you will not have really-really smooth delete animation as if you just call `deleteRows`. But you can try. Maybe for small amount of data it works fine.

Comment: I agree with this recommendation. Delete the object from the realm and then in your realm notification block, update your `UICollectionView`'. Realm is super fast and can handle thousands of objects without issue.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum, yes, sure. All realm queries are lazy, so there are no any kind of "load everything from everywhere you can" things. Big advantage of realm.